# Are class/struct functions stored in an object?

Tags: c++, class, object, storage

Assuming this:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B {
    int a;
    int b;

    int func() {
        return this->a + this->b;
    }
};
```

Would an instance of `B` contain a pointer to `func`?

To illustrate this question in code:

```
A a; // first 4 bytes are for `int a`, second 4 bytes are for `int b`
B b: // ditto, but is there an extra word for a pointer to function `func`?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Both `a` and `b` are exactly the same size (`b` does not store a pointer to `func`).

Class functions in C++ are not linked (pointed) from the object itself, they are simply stored as any other function. When you call a class function, you are simply calling a normal function (you are not calling it from a pointer). This is why doing something like `b.func = another_func;` is illegal in C++.

To illustrate this in code:

```
/////////
// C++
/////////
struct B {
    int a;
    int b;

    int func() {
        return this->a + this->b;
    }
};

B b;
b.func();


//////////////////////////////
// Example compile output if it was compiled to C (not actual compile output!)
// i.e. this C code will do the equivalent of the C++ code above
//////////////////////////////
struct B {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int B_func(struct B* this) {
    return this->a + this->b;
}

B b;
B_func(&b);

// This should illustrate why it is impossible to do this in C++:
// b.func = another_func;
```

Comment: You might want to add that *virtual* functions are a bit different.

Comment: Member functions are not exactly "any normal functions". They do have hidden `this` argument. In fact, your C example is precisely what C++ compiler will do... Maybe your wording confused me and you actually meant exactly that.

Comment: @PetrBudnik Yes, my wording isn't the best :P Basically, what I meant was, when you call a member function, you're just calling it normally, and not through a pointer stored inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

C++ functions are really just functions which (potentially) take a hidden pointer to the object as the first parameter. Uniqueness is achieved through [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Unless the function is virtual; classes which have one or more virtual functions have a "virtual function table" (vtable) and instances of those classes have the overhead of a pointer to their instance-specific vtable. Whether the vtable is before or after the object depends on the compiler/implementation.